# How to access Spring Bean from JerseyTest subclass

Tags: java, spring, testing, jersey, jersey-2.0

Here is my abstract class which starts Jersey with given Spring context:

```
public abstract class AbstractJerseyTest extends JerseyTest {

public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
}

@AfterClass
public void destroy() throws Exception {
    tearDown();
}

@Override
protected URI getBaseUri() {
    return URI.create("http://localhost:9993");
}

@Override
protected Application configure() {
    RestApplication application = new RestApplication();

    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    properties.put(ServerProperties.BV_SEND_ERROR_IN_RESPONSE, true);
    properties.put("contextConfigLocation", "classpath:spring-context-test.xml");

    application.setProperties(properties);
    application.register(this);
    return application;
}
}
```

So, the problem is that I need to access Spring bean from my test to populate database with some data.

Jersey version is 2.6

Also I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666105/accessing-spring-beans-in-jerseytest)

But it's related to Jersey 1.x so it doesn't work for Jersey 2.x

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was really simple.
I added:

```
@Autowired
private Repository repository;
```

to the AbstractJerseyTest and this field was automatically autowired during test startup. I don't know details about how it works, but it seems that when I register instance of the test in REST application

```
application.register(this);
```

it automatically autowires all beans in the test.

Comment: Ahhh.. . Sometimes I miss the obvious. I didn't even notice that you registered the test class. It makes perfect sense.

Comment: Actually, after some further testing, I believe that this is some bug, that this works. It definitely is not a feature, as I get a logged warning _"WARNING: A provider SimpleTest registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider SimpleTest will be ignored."_. Do you get this same warning? I say it's a bug because even though the class is injected, it is not registered as a service that can be injected into something else. I'd have to look more into it.

Comment: @peeskillet, I didn't find the warning you mentioned. However it can be related to the logger settings.

Answer (score 1):

Normally in your case, I'd just say work with mocks, but there are cases where you may need to expose the services in the test class.

To do this without any "ugly hacks", you will need to get a handle on the `ServiceLocator` (which is analogous to Spring's `ApplicationContext`). When the Jersey app boots up, all the Spring services from the `ApplicationContext` are put into the `ServiceLocator` through HK2's Spring bridge.

The problem is `JerseyTest` does not expose the `ServiceLocator` in any way. The only way I can think of to get a hold of it, is to create your own `TestContainerFactory`, and create the `ApplicationHandler`, which exposes the `ServiceLocator`.

Trying to implement your own `TestContainerFactory` is not a walk in the park, if you don't know what you're doing. The easiest thing to do is just look at the source code for Jersey's [`InMemoryTestContainerFactory`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/test-framework/providers/inmemory/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/test/inmemory/InMemoryTestContainerFactory.java#L61). If you look at the constructor for the inner class `InMemoryTestContainer`, you will see it creating the `ApplicationHandler`. This is how you can expose the `ServiceLocator`, through the `appHandler.getServiceLocator()`.

So if you copied that class, and exposed the `ServiceLocator`, you could create your `JerseyTest` extension, and call the `ServiceLocator.inject(Object)` method to inject the test class.

```
public abstract class AbstractServiceLocatorAwareJerseyTest extends JerseyTest {
    
    private final ServiceLocatorAwareInMemoryTestContainerFactory factory
            = new ServiceLocatorAwareInMemoryTestContainerFactory();
    private ServiceLocator locator;
    
    @Override
    public TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() {
        return factory;
    }
    
    @Before
    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        this.locator = factory.getServiceLocator();
        if (injectTestClass()) {
            this.locator.inject(this);
        }
    }
    
    public boolean injectTestClass() {
        return true;
    }
    
    public ServiceLocator getServiceLocator() {
        return locator;
    }
}
```

And if for any reason you needed it, the `ServiceLocator` also has the `ApplicationContext`, which you could also expose to your test class if needed.

I put together a [GitHub project](https://github.com/psamsotha/jersey-spring-test-utils), with a complete implementation, with tests if you want to take a look at it.

---

### UPDATE

Though the OP's answer to this question works, I believe the fact that it works, is a bug. I originally deleted this answer, after the OP posted their answer, but after some testing, I believe that solution is a bug, so I've undeleted this post for anyone who doesn't like the warning<sup>**1**</sup> you get when you use that solution

---

<sub>1. "WARNING: A provider SimpleTest registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider SimpleTest will be ignored."</sub>

Comment: please see the answer I posted